# Shape Openness detection in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, contour, shapes

I'm building a shape analysis algorithm and one of the attributes we would like to add is whether the shape is open or closed. For example, the left circle is closed, the middle circle is open and the right circle is **more** open.

[image]

I tried to do it via the contours but I search for a more robust (and hopefully easy) way to achieve it. I know it can be solved with ANN but I don't want to go in that direction.
(I'm working with Python/OpenCV 4)

Any ideas?

Comment: I have an approach that uses contours but its a bit tricky to explain. What approach did you use when you tried to do it via contours?

Comment: My contour approach doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great way to do it using ImageDraw.floodfill function.
Attached is a working code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def openOrClose(img2):
   isCLosed = False
   img = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
   target_pixel = (0,0) #Corner of the image
   target_color = (255,255,0) #Yellow
   im_pil = Image.fromarray(img)

   ImageDraw.floodfill(im_pil,target_pixel,target_color)
   im = np.asarray(im_pil)

   count =0 
   for i in range(im.shape[0]):
      for j in range(im.shape[1]):
        if ((im[i][j] == [255,255,255]).all() == True):
            count+=1
   if count != 0:
     isCLosed = True   
  return isCLosed
```

and this is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the object is the only thing in the array you are analyzing you could flood fill from any of the corners. If the area occupied by your flood fill value is less than the image area with the drawing's area subtracted it would be a closed object.

Comment: Should be a comment. I know you don't have enough reputation. Please be patience after 15 reputation you will be able to comment.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, i will do so from now on. As you noticed i am pretty new to the actual contributing here

Comment: I too started not too long ago. But it is really fun to see how fast the progress can come when you spend time on it and have good resources to draw on

Comment: I came across this tutorial - https://medium.com/@elvisdias/introduction-to-opencv-with-python-i-9fc72082f230